# want to add spring boot 2.1.6 version?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

[image]

Hi, I wanna create a project which has a 2.1.6 version of the spring boot. Is there any way that I can add this version onto the Intellij's choice?

Answer (score 0):

After generating v2.1.15 project, you need to edit `pom.xml` yourself.

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Edit `<version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>` to `<version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>`.